# Connecting to paired bluetooth device (BluetoothSocket) in android 2.1

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am trying to connect to a paired `bluetooth` device (baracoda d-fly bar code reader). I tried the program `GetBlueDemo` from market and this manages to read from its socket.

I wrote my own proof of concept, but i just keep getting an excpetion when i try to connect to the device.

```
08-23 14:39:28.635: DEBUG/BluetoothTest(19238): Could not connect to socket
08-23 14:39:28.635: DEBUG/BluetoothTest(19238): java.io.IOException: socket failed to connect
08-23 14:39:28.635: DEBUG/BluetoothTest(19238):     at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.connect(BluetoothSocket.java:255)
08-23 14:39:28.635: DEBUG/BluetoothTest(19238):     at org.me.barcodetest.MainActivity$ConnectRunnable.run(MainActivity.java:211)
08-23 14:39:28.635: DEBUG/BluetoothTest(19238):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1102)
```

Any suggestions on what i am doing wrong?

```
package org.me.barcodetest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.AlertDialog.Builder;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnCancelListener;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.UUID;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 2;
private BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter;
private UUID applicationUUID = java.util.UUID.randomUUID();
private static final String logTag = "BluetoothTest";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    if (bluetoothAdapter == null) {
        Log.d(logTag, "Could not get bluetooth adapter");
        return;
    }
    searchForDevices();
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_ENABLE_BT) {
        if (requestCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Log.d("BluetoothTest", "bluetooth enabled");
            searchForDevices();
        } else {
            Log.d("BluetoothTest", "Could not enable bluetooth device");
        }
    }

}

public void lineReadFromBluetoothDevice(String line) {
    Log.d(logTag, "Mottok: " + line);
}

private void searchForDevices() {
    if (bluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        Set<BluetoothDevice> devicesAvailable = bluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
        if (devicesAvailable.isEmpty()) {
            informUserNoDevicesPaired();
        } else {
            askUserToPickDeviceToUse(devicesAvailable);
        }
    } else {
        Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
    }
}

private void askUserToPickDeviceToUse(Set<BluetoothDevice> devicesAvailable) {
    final ListView view = new ListView(this);
    view.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
    ArrayAdapter<BluetoothDevice> adapter =
            new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.devicesavailabletextview, devicesAvailable.toArray(new BluetoothDevice[devicesAvailable.size()])) {

                @Override
                public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                    TextView view = (TextView) super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                    BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice = (BluetoothDevice) getItem(position);
                    view.setText(bluetoothDevice.getName() + " : " + bluetoothDevice.getAddress());
                    return view;
                }
            };
    view.setAdapter(adapter);
    view.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
            pairToDevice((BluetoothDevice) view.getItemAtPosition(position));
        }
    });


    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
    dialog.setContentView(view);
    dialog.setCancelable(true);
    dialog.show();

}

private void informUserNoDevicesPaired() {
    Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    dialogBuilder.setMessage("Ingen \"Paired\" enheter");
    dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Søk", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int arg1) {
            dialog.dismiss();

        }
    });
    dialogBuilder.setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener() {

        public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            finish();
        }
    });
    dialogBuilder.show();
}

private void showError(String message) {
    Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    dialogBuilder.setMessage("Det oppstod en feil i programmet:\n\n" + message);
    dialogBuilder.setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener() {

        public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            finish();
        }
    });
    dialogBuilder.show();
}

private void pairToDevice(BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice) {
    openSocket(bluetoothDevice);
}

private void openSocket(BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice) {
    try {

        final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        final ConnectRunnable connector = new ConnectRunnable(bluetoothDevice, dialog);
        dialog.show(this, "Kobler til", "Koblier til " + bluetoothDevice.getName() + " : " + bluetoothDevice.getAddress(),
                true, true,
                new OnCancelListener() {

                    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                        connector.cancel();
                    }
                });

        new Thread(connector).start();

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Log.d(logTag, "Could not open bluetooth socket", ex);
        showError("Kunne ikke åpne socket grunnet feil: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
}

private void closeSocket(BluetoothSocket openSocket) {
    try {
        openSocket.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Log.d(logTag, "Could not close exisiting socket", ex);
    }
}

private void startListeningForInput(BluetoothSocket socket) {
    new Thread(new InputReader(socket)).start();

}

private void dismissDialog(final Dialog dialog) {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
}

private class ConnectRunnable implements Runnable {

    private final ProgressDialog dialog;
    private final BluetoothSocket socket;

    public ConnectRunnable(BluetoothDevice device, ProgressDialog dialog) throws IOException {
        socket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(applicationUUID);
        this.dialog = dialog;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
            socket.connect();
        } catch (IOException connectException) {
            Log.d(logTag, "Could not connect to socket", connectException);
            closeSocket(socket);
            return;
        }
        startListeningForInput(socket);
        dismissDialog(dialog);
    }

    public void cancel() {
        try {
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(logTag, "Canceled connection", e);
        }
    }
}

private class InputReader implements Runnable {

    private final BluetoothSocket socket;

    public InputReader(BluetoothSocket socket) {
        this.socket = socket;

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            final InputStream input = socket.getInputStream();
            final BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input, "UTF-8"));
            String line;

            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                lineReadFromBluetoothDevice(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            showError("Mistet forbindelsen: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void cancel() {
        try {
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
}
}



     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
```

devicesavailabletextview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</TextView>
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem was my uuid, i figured this was just an uuid for android to know where it came from, but it had to be "00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"

Comment: I ran your code on HTC desire, it is giving exception. Can you please let me know anything I am missing?

Comment: Hi there, I used the same method but it stuck with the dialog named "Kobler til". Does it connect to your paired device? Please guide me to connect with paired Bluetooth device. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you that totally helped me. Where did you find that info? Im just curious.

Answer (score 3):

The barcode scanner uses the SPP protocol - so your have to use the SPP UUID to connect to it.